# Showing that a discrete-time system has one equilibrium

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, dynamical-systems, network

I have the following discrete-time system:

$$x(k + 1) = Bx(k) + c$$

where $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Assuming $B$ is convergent, how can I show the following?

1. The matrix $(I_n - B)$ is invertible
2. The only equilibrium point of the system is $(I_n - B)^{-1}c$

---

Thus far, I have:

$$I_n - B = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   1 & 0  \\
   0 & 1  \\    
 \end{array} } \right] - \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   b_{11} & b_{12}  \\
   0 & b_{22}  \\    
 \end{array} } \right] = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   1-b_{11} & b_{12}  \\
   0 & 1-b_{22}  \\    
 \end{array} } \right]$$

Since the determinant of this resulting matrix is never zero (assuming $b_{11} \neq 1$ and $b_{22} \neq 1$), does this show that $(I_n - B)$ is invertible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can verify by multiplication that $(I-B)(I+B+B^{2}+....+B^{n})=I-B^{n+1}$.

Since $B$ is convergent we have that lim$\left\|B^{n} \right\|$=$0$  $\,\,(1)$

we can show that the series $I+B+B^{2}+.....$ converges, since by Corollary p.151 Kantorovich: Functional Analysis a necessary and

sufficient for the series to converge is that for some $k$ we have

$\left\|B^{k} \right\|<1$. But we already have that, since

lim$\left\|B^{n} \right\|$=$0$ .

So the series $I+B+B^{2}+.....=V$ and we have $(I-B)V=I$ and likewise that $V(I-B)=I$.

So $I-B$ is invertible and hence the equilibrium point is $x=(I-B)^{-1}c$.

Comment: I do not understand how you derived the equilibrium point. Could you elaborate on that part?

Comment: If $x_{k+1}=F(x_{k})$ we just solve $x=F(x)$. See this https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Scientific_Computing_Simulations_and_Modeling/Book%3A_Introduction_to_the_Modeling_and_Analysis_of_Complex_Systems_(Sayama)/05%3A_DiscreteTime_Models_II__Analysis/5.01%3A_Finding_Equilibrium_Points

Comment: I am really sorry but I am not following. I understand your proof of convergence. However, how does $(I - B)V = I$ when we started by saying $(I - B)(I + B + B^2 +...+B^n) = I- B^{n+1}$?

Comment: Since the series is convergent we call it V. Also lim$B^{n+1}=0$ so taking limits on both sides we get$ (I-B)V=I$

Comment: I have two final questions: how did you know to start the proof by multiplying $(I - B)$ by the series $I + B + B^2...$? Is there an intuitive reason for this? Moreover, how does $(I - B)V = I$ and $V(I - B) = I$ proof irreducibility? (sorry, I am fairly new to linear algebra)

Comment: It is a standard trick. I read it in Kantorovich: Functional Analysis!